# Representing a binary number in C

Tags: c, binary

How to create an integer whose binary representation is : `000...01101110` 
So the first three bits from left are 0 and right most 8 bits are given 
one way I can think of is declaring an integer like `int k =0b000....01101110;` 
What are other ways which could be used to declare an int like this?

Comment: What's wrong with the one way that you know? Why do you need more ways than that?

Comment: If you wish to work with binary numbers, I would recommend storing them in arrays.

Comment: You can use bit shifting and masking. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Where do the middle bits with `...` come from?

Comment: The value of an int is irrelevant for the declaration. Please decide what you want do with your int: output, init, read from user...